# WebGL not working on chromium or firefox

Tags: graphics, firefox, chromium, webgl

Im using Xubuntu 20.04 and I've been having trouble with firefox and chromium to use WebGL. In chromium it only works if I activate hardware acceleration but it works slow because of my integrated video card (Intel G33/31).

I tried to test webgl on firefox and it doesn't work either.

In windows 7 it works perfectly without problems, and previously I used linux mint and it also worked but now the problem appears when using xubuntu 20.04

```
Chromium gpu test:
Graphics Feature Status
Canvas: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Flash: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Flash Stage3D: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Flash Stage3D Baseline profile: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Compositing: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Multiple Raster Threads: Disabled
Out-of-process Rasterization: Disabled
OpenGL: Disabled
Hardware Protected Video Decode: Disabled
Rasterization: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Skia Renderer: Enabled
Video Decode: Software only. Hardware acceleration disabled
Viz Display Compositor: Enabled
Vulkan: Disabled
WebGL: Disabled
WebGL2: Disabled
```

On firefox:

```
WebGL 1 Driver Renderer WebGL creation failed: 
* tryNativeGL
* Exhausted GL driver options.
```

Inxi details:

```
inxi -SGx
System:
  Host: zyrox-home Kernel: 5.4.0-33-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc 
  v: 9.3.0 Desktop: Xfce 4.14.2 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel 82G33/G31 Express Integrated Graphics vendor: Lenovo 
  driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: intel 
  unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,vesa resolution: 1280x1024~75Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa DRI Intel G33 v: 1.4 Mesa 20.0.4 direct render: Yes
```

Comment: I ran into this problem with an nvidia card due to the nvidia libs being updated in the background while the old kernel was still running.  Do standalone OpenGL apps work like `glxinfo` and `glxgears`?  Are there any errors about DRI/DRM in `dmesg`?